# No route matches [POST] "/basic_pages/basic_pages/home"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

So I would simply like to post to my root. My problem is that if I try to do it the second time (first time works fine) I am posting /basic_pages/basic_pages/home instead of /basic_pages/home. Why does that happen and how do I fix this?

home.html.erb:

```
<h1>BasicPages#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/basic_pages/home.html.erb</p>

<%= form_tag ('basic_pages/home') do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :my_input %>
   <%= submit_tag "Send input" %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'basic_pages#home'

  post 'basic_pages/home'

  get 'about' => 'basic_pages#about'

end
```

Hope this provides all the information necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `form_tag ('basic_pages/home')` use `form_tag ('/basic_pages/home')`. When you have posted the url is getting changed to /basic_pages/home, and then the form is again posting to /basic_pages/basic_pages/home, because of the relative path given to the form.

Comment: ughh... so simple. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  post '/' => "basic_pages#home", as: "root"

  get 'about' => 'basic_pages#about'

end
```

home.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag ('/') do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :my_input %>
   <%= submit_tag "Send input" %>
<% end %>
```